# Why is "sew" pronounced as "so"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, irregular

Why is *[sew](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sew)* (`/səʊ/` or `/sō/`) pronounced similar to *so* rather than to *few* or *sue*?

Looking at its [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sew),

> Old English siwian "to stitch," earlier **siowian**, from Proto-Germanic *siwjanan (cf. Old Norse syja, Swedish sy, Old High German siuwan, Gothic siujan "to sew"), from PIE root *syu- "to bind, sew" (cf. Sanskrit sivyati "sews," sutram "thread, string;" Greek hymen "thin skin, membrane," hymnos "song;" Latin suere "to sew, sew together;" Old Church Slavonic sijo "to sew," sivu "seam;" Lettish siuviu, siuti "to sew," siuvikis "tailor;" Russian svec "tailor"). Related: Sewed; sewing. Sewing machine is attested from 1847.

*siowian* appears to be the only word which could have been pronounced with a `/səʊ/`. But the later spelling of *siwian* sounds unlikely to have been pronounced so.

Also, are there other similarly spelt words which have the same irregularity in pronunciation?

Comment: You missed one. *So*, *sew*, and also *sow* are all perfect homophones of one another, all being pronounced `[soʊ]`. But *sewer* does not sound like *sower*.

Comment: @tchrist While they can be near-perfect homophones, the female pig rhymes with _how_.

Comment: Er, so what?  I wasn’t talking about female pigs.  One *sows* seeds; one does not *sew* them.  Seeds are *sown*; threads are *sewn*.

Comment: @tchrist What I meant was that I do not want to complicate the question by adding a word with multiple pronunciations. _Sew-so_ is all that I'm interested in.

Comment: But *sew* itself has multiple pronunciations, since a *cow that’s gone sew* (=dry) is pronounced  `[sjuː]`.

Comment: @tchrist That's interesting. It appears to be the verb form of _sewer_. I've never come across this form before.

Comment: @tchrist: A *sewer* with thread and a *sower* with seeds are certainly homophones to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes of course, but a stinky sewer is not.

Comment: Also, in the original King James Bible, written in Elizabethan English, the word "show" is spelled "shew."

Comment: Sew is sow? How about know and knew? Sew as sow is far off. Unless its just being pronounced that way because of it's old word. Almost like pounds as lbs. But it came from libras. English is really funny. New and now is not same word but you get the idea why sew and sow is funny.

Answer (score 7):

The OED’s etymology entry notes that it is abnormal, but does not say how this came to be.

> **Etymology:**  Com. Teut. and Indogermanic: OE. *siwan*, 
>   *siowan* (usually, with change of conjugation, *siwian*, 
>   *siowian*, *seowian*) = OFris. *sîa* (mod.Fris. dial. 
>   *siije*), OHG. *siuwen*, ONor. *sýja* (Sw. *sy*, Da.
>   *sye*), Goth. *siujan* :— OTeut. **siwjan*, cogn. w. the
>   synonymous L. *su-ĕre*, Gr. (κασ-)σύειν, Lett. *schuju*, OSl.
>   *šiti* (Russ. *shitp.*, *shivatp.*), Skr. *siv*
>   (3 sing. pres. *sīvyati*, pa. pple. *syūtá*; derivatives are
>   *syū* fem., needle or thread, *syūman* suture).
>
> The root (for which Hirt suggests a primary form **seyewa-*) appears
>   in the words above quoted as **syū-* : **sīw*.  Another
>   ablaut-grade, **syou-*, is found in OTeut. **saumo-*  **seam**  *sb.* The
>   pronunciation `[səʊ]` is abnormal (cf. *strow*, var. of
>   *strew*, repr. OE. *streowian*); the written forms show that it
>   goes back at least to the 14th c.  In the 17th c. *sew* sometimes
>   rhymes with *clue*, *new*; the mod.Sc. pronunciation is 
>   `[ʃu]`.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea what _mod.Sc._ stands for? Scottish?

Comment: @coleopterist Aye.

Comment: The word [show](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=show) also used to be pronounced *shew*, and has an archaic spelling "shew". So both of these words underwent the same change in pronunciation, but only "shew" changed its spelling.

Comment: @Peter: My English teacher (a *long* time ago!) always pronounced it *shew*. None of us pupils were ever tempted to copy him, though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think they might be something afoot with *strew, strewn*, too, to judge from the OED notes.

Comment: @tchrist Shouldn't that be *Och, aye*?

Comment: @PeterShor- Is *that* where Ed Sullivan got it?

Answer (score 4):

Although I can't explain why the shift occurred, I found an interesting item in an 1839 Vermont newspaper that suggests that at that time and in that place some cultivated (or would-be cultivated) English speakers may have viewed the "so" pronunciation of *sew* as a vulgarism.

From "[Vulgarisms](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn98060050/1839-01-18/ed-1/seq-4/#words=%22squinch%22)" in the *[Brattleboro] Vermont Phoenix* (January 18, 1839):

> The following list of unpardonable vulgarisms, were published in a New Hampshire paper, half a century ago. It was prepared for the use of a school, and it is said, proved highly beneficial.
>
> These inaccuracies of pronunciation are not confined to New Hampshire, but exist now, as well as formerly, in different parts of New England. Many might be added to the list—and it should be the one of the most important duties of an instructor of youth, to do away with these barbarous *provincialisms*:
>
> ...
>
> Shot or Shet for Shut.
>
> Shear for Share.
>
> **So for Sew.**
>
> Sot for Sat or Set.
>
> Sor for Saw.

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) gives only one pronunciation for *sew*—the unpardonably vulgar **'sō**—as indeed does every other Webster's Collegiate edition, going back to the first edition (1898). This would seem to suggest that the correct pronunciation of *sew*, according to the *Vermont Phoenix*, effectively died out rather quickly in the United States, between 1839 and 1898.

Further research on this point, however, makes the newspaper item even more dubious. Noah Webster, *An American Dictionary of the English Language* (1828) begins its entry for *sew* as follows:

> **SEW,** *v. t.* pronounced *so*, and better written *soe*. {Sax[on] *siwian*, *suwian* ; Goth[ic] *siuyan* ; Sw[edish] *sy* ; Dan[ish] *syer* ; L[atin] *suo*.} This is probably a contracted word, and if its elements are *Sb* or *Sf*, it coincides with Eth[iopic] ~~~ *shafai*, to sew ; and the Ar[abic] has ~~~ an awl. ... The Hindoo has *siwawa*, and the Gipsey *siwena*. But the elements are not obvious.}

Webster was a native of Connecticut and would certainly have been aware of a different—and preferred—pronunciation of *sew* among cultivated New Englanders if it existed. Since he indicates no such awareness, I think the likelier explanation is that the objection to "So for Sew" in the 1839 Vermont newspaper isn't objection to pronunciation at all, but to phonetic spelling. If this is the case, though, it is striking that the newspaper views *so* as a barbarous provincialism at the same time that Webster endorses *soe* as a "better" way to spell *sew*.